# Angular - Proper way to share reaction between sibling components

Tags: angular, typescript, design-patterns

The title is not very explanatory, but I couldn't find any better way to phrase my problem.

I'm working with angular, and I've been facing a problem a few times now. Let me show it as an example :

Let's say I have a mother component `MomComponent`, which contains multiple `KidComponent`.

Each `KidComponent` can be resized by the user. If that happens, all of the other kids should be resized as well.

A Kid component should also be able to live without siblings.

Here's my code :

```js
// mom.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-mom',
    templateUrl: './mom.component.html',
})
export class MomComponent {
    width: number;
}
```

```html
<!-- mom.component.html -->

<app-kid [(width)]="width"></app-kid>

<app-kid [(width)]="width"></app-kid>

<app-kid [(width)]="width"></app-kid>
```

```js
// kid.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-kid',
    templateUrl: './kid.component.html',
})
export class KidComponent {
    @Input() set width(w: number) {
        this._width = w;
        this.draw();
    }
    @Output() widthChange = new EventEmitter<number>();

    private _width = 100;

    onUserResize(newWidth: number) {
        this.widthChange.emit(newWidth);

        this._width = newWidth;
        this.draw();
    }

    draw() {
        // Drawing code
    }
}
```

---

**My problem here, is that the kid which has been resized will be drawn 2 times. One first time because I call it internally, and a second time because the mom's variable `width` will be updated.**

I could change my kid component as follows, so that it's only redrawn from external change :

```js
// kid.component.ts
export class KidComponent {
    // [...]

    onUserResize(newWidth: number) {
        this.widthChange.emit(newWidth);

        // I remove these 2 lines:
        //
        // this._width = newWidth;
        // this.draw();
    }
  
    // [...]
}
```

But then, I also want to be able to use my `KidComponent` on its own without sharing its width with other kids (just `<app-kid></app-kid>`), in which case, the above code wouldn't work.

---

The only solution that I can think of right now is the following :

```js
// kid.component.ts
export class KidComponent {
    // [...]

    onUserResize(newWidth: number) {
        this.widthChange.emit(newWidth);

        if (!this.widthChange.observers.length) {
            // No-one is listening to the event, I redraw myself
            this._width = newWidth;
            this.draw();
        } else {
            // Someone is listening to my resize, let's hope they
            // take care of redrawing me...
        }
    }

    // [...]
}
```

But I don't really like this approach, the fact that there is an observer on the `widthChage` emitter doesn't mean that this observer will redraw the `KidComponent`.

So, my question is : **Is there a better approach that I'm missing?**

Thanks!

Comment: One simple suggestion:
In the Function 'onUserResize' set _width with the new with and call draw() and then emit the new width.
In the setter of width only call draw() if _width !== width

This way your KidComponent gets a redraw if you (the user) changes its width or it gets a redraw if some other KidComponent emited a new value to MotherComponent.

Btw.: Remove the draw() call in OnUserResize and use this.width instead of this._width to call the setter which calls draw() anyway and then emit the value to MotherComponent for other interessted parties.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think about that! Thanks a lot, you can write it as a solution, I'll approve it

Comment: See: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-using-a-service for communicating via a service, which is the best way IMO to communicate between siblings so that you're not polluting a higher-order component with code that is unrelated to its purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in my comment (simple suggestion):

```
// kid.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-kid',
    templateUrl: './kid.component.html',
})
export class KidComponent {
    @Input() set width(w: number) {
        if(this._width === w) return;
        this._width = w;
        this.draw();
    }

    @Output() widthChange = new EventEmitter<number>();

    private _width = 100;

    onUserResize(newWidth: number) {
        this.width = newWith;
        this.widthChange.emit(newWidth);
    }

    draw() {
        // Drawing code
    }
}
```

As Brandon Tylor mentioned you could also use services for communication between siblings but i don't know if it is not going to get complicated because you just need one property.